# PayPal Donate SDK - Prefill Amount and Frequency

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am building an application which includes a custom donation form where users can select:

- Frequency: monthly, single
- Amount: 3 x Buttons with values, input for custom value

[image]

I am using the PayPal Donate SDK and cannot find a way to pass across the amount or frequency so that the amount is pre-filled and the "make this a monthly donation" checkbox selected/deselected based on the users input.

The PayPal button has been added to the page (just absolute styled over the form button) and the SDK opens the donation page in a modal which is my desired result.

This is the code to display my button:

```
window.PayPal.Donation.Button({
    env: "sandbox",
    hosted_button_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    onComplete: function() {
        // Redirect to success page, save the PP transaction details, etc.
    }
}).render("#paypal-donate-button-container");
```

With the standard `PayPal.Buttons` API, I am able to pass in a `createOrder` function like so, where I can set the amount, for example;

```
window.PayPal.Buttons({
    // ...
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: document.querySelector(".selected-premium").dataset.value
                },
                reference_id: document.querySelector(".selected-premium").dataset.days + "-days"
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass through the amount and frequency using the SDK, similar to how I can do it with the standard payments API? If not, what are the alternatives in 2022 that don't rely on SO answers that use docs that no longer exist/deprecated methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the PayPal Donations flow (this includes the Donate SDK)

- You can pass a parameter for the `amount` and `currency_code`. If you do pass a prefilled amount, an option to make the donation recurring will *not* be available.
- You cannot pre select the option to make the donation recurring in the Donations flow.

---

For the case of recurring donations -- since it's not possible to precheck the option to make them recurring in the Donations flow, nor is it possible to prefill the amount and have that choice of recurrence even be available -- what you could do is instead use a Subscription flow for when a recurrence is selected, and have this render in a separate div container that is shown/hidden based on your monthly vs single selection. A subscribe button for your account can be generated at: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans . The plan it uses must have a specific amount, but this [can be overridden](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body) in the JS `createSubscription` function (based on whatever selection or amount was entered on your site) by (in addition to the base `plan_id`) adding a `plan` object that contains a `billing_cycles` object with the amount/frequency you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - unfortunately when I set `amount` and `currency_code` as properties on the object passed into `PayPal.Donation.Button()`, this isn't reflected on the PP donation page, I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something. Thanks for the info regarding subscriptions.

Comment: That's because you're using a hosted_button_id . Change to specifying a `business` parameter with your PayPal Merchant ID https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness or the account's primary email